# Bind enum value on angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

Is there any way I can bind enum value to my angular material table?

For example: I have an enum.

```
export enum EnumName {
  val1 = 1,
  val2 = 2,
  val3 = 3
}
```

and then on my angular material table I want to display.

```
Id   EnumNameColumn
1    val2
2    val3
3    val1
```

Not like this.

```
Id   EnumNameColumn
1    2
2    3
3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to extract the strings out of the enum. the result gets delivered in a string array:

Use the `getKeyListOfEnum()` method

```
public getKeyListOfEnum<T>(enm: T): Array<string> {
    let retVal = [];

    if (this.isEnum(enm)) {

        // extract the keys of the enum (Strings only!)
        retVal = Object.keys(enm).filter(
            k => typeof enm[k as any] === 'number'
        );
    }

    return retVal;
}


// check whether it is an ENUM
private isEnum(instance: Object): boolean {
    const keys = Object.keys(instance);
    const values = [];

    for (const key of keys) {
        let value = instance[key];

        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            value = value.toString();
        }

        values.push(value);
    }

    for (const key of keys) {
        if (values.indexOf(key) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

And then you can use it somehow like this:

```
export enum Fruit {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE,
    PEAR
}


keyArray: Array<string> = [];
keyArray = this.getKeyListOfEnum(Fruit);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some like

```
dataSource = Object.keys(EnumName)
    .filter((x:any)=>x==Number(x))
    .map((x:any)=>({key:x,value:EnumName[x]}));
```